# Is it good practice to partially use a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I'm writing a class that represents a model in a database. Some of the data in that model is created by the database and it's not known at the time of creation. This is a little example of what I'm talking about:

```
public class Person {
    public int id { get; private set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    // Methods to load and update...
}
```

This class would have methods to load the data from the database and to update changes made into the database.

Now, my questions are:

- Should I use this class for creating new `Person` records into my database?
- Or should I create a new class that only has the properties required to create a new person?

Again, my reasoning is that I can't know the id field at creation time, so maybe I should not use the same class.

I hope you can help me with this dilemma.

Comment: You should read about repository pattern.

Comment: You are reinventing the fire, do you know about entity framework? its is basicly what you are defining here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx, Entity framework creates another class that makes all CRUD operations, you only give the model

Comment: In the entity framework all properties are writable. I want to make sure I don't change anything I shouldn't by mistake.

Comment: If you don't want certain fields to be in the model, then just remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcel,

Short answers: Yes for your first question, no for your second question.

Theory is your class should have all members that are required for your application. If the database table contains keys, then by definition they must appear in your class or else your program would not be able to add rows. By making your class adhere to the requirements of the database table as well as your program's requirements, this class will be suitable for adding, updating, even searching. If you begin to pick and choose which fields to add, you'll then need to pick and choose which class to use for each operation, causing confusion that may ultimately waste your time.

That's not to say you have to have every column in your class; if the application does not require the column, you do not need to include it.

There was a previous comment regarding entity frameworks, that require you build this type of class, or "Entity" as it's then called.

Comment: Actually, I asked the question. Marcel just did a little of editing for clarity. Anyway, I guess you're right. Although, what Marcin and bto.rdz mentioned, Repository pattern and Entity Framework, seems to be what I'm trying to ultimately accomplish.